# How to use CASE or IF (etc) ... statements in JOIN clause?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have several tables in the database with the names `data`, `sticker` and `video`

And inside the `sticker` and video tables... I have a foreign key called `data_id` (which is actually linked to the `data` table)

In the `data` table, I have a column called `type` that stores the "**data type**" (for example `sticker` or `video`, etc...)

I want to find the corresponding table with SQL based on the `type` column and do a **join** between them, but I don't know how to do it (querying it first becomes advanced and complicated)

**For example, something like this:**

```sql
SELECT d.name

FROM data d

IF (d.type == 'sticker') JOIN sticker s on d.id = s.data_id
ELSEIF (d.type == 'video') JOIN video v on d.id = v.data_id
# ...

WHERE d.id = 2;
```

**I know that `IF` and `ELSEIF` part is completely wrong in the query**, I just wanted to convey the concept and tell you what I want... I don't know how to do it correctly in sql...

**Can you help me???**

....................................................................

Comment: Your problem really stems from a poor design and relying on the data present in a row to determine the join condition; at a guess these tables are the same or have similar columns and should be a single table with an additional *type* column; you have to join both tables and then use the value that is not null - you don't show your entire query though.

Comment: Can you share sample input data from your tables and expected output?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a `CASE` expression here.  I would express your query using exists logic:

```sql
SELECT name
FROM data d
WHERE
    type == 'sticker' AND
    EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM sticker s
        WHERE d.id = s.data_id
    )
    OR
    type == 'video' AND
    EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM video v
        WHERE d.id = v.data_id
    );
```

As mentioned in the comments, and is indicated by the complexity of the above query, you seem to have a design problem.  The `video` and `sticker` tables should probably be merged with a new column for the type being added.